# What font is this? 1920's, 1930's, Art Deco, Italian, but simple

Tags: font-identification

Looking for a match or similar font to the text on these signs. Particularly the "D" on the middle sign and "R" on the right most sign -- how they're fatter on the bottom of the curve. Any ideas appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I doubt that it has a name. Those signs were most likely hand-painted.

I can only see similarities between the letter forms - not uniformity. Take the M in "Morte" vs "Miscarriage". Nonetheless it looks like a compressed Copperplate to me.

Comment: Agreed. Handpainted